# Fancybox gallery breaks swiper

Tags: javascript, fancybox, swiper.js

Fancybox breaks swiper. Adds offset without visible CSS and DOM changes. To replicate the issue on jsbin (https://output.jsbin.com/jiqucacete) you need:

```
new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  slidesPerView: 1
});
```

1) Press on the swiper slide image
2) Go to next image in fancybox gallery popup
3) Close gallery and there will be slide change in swiper

How does it work? 
Why there aren't visible any CSS, DOM changes?
How to fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fancybox places focus back on the trigger element after closing the gallery and sometimes carousel/slider scripts are sensitive to this feature. To disable that, set `backFocus:false`, for example:

```
$.fancybox.defaults.backFocus = false;
```

Comment: This answer saved my day :)

Comment: This save my night!!! Thanks a lot!